# default indexes in DynamoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing, amazon-dynamodb

Are there any indexes created by default in DynamoDB? Like in MongoDB, there is the _id field that automatically indexes the document. Does DynamoDB have anything like that and if so, what is it called?

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing in DynamoDB.

When you create a DDB table, you need to define it's [primary key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey) - it can be either only a partition key (basically and unique ID) or a combination of a partition key and a sort key (also called a composite primary key). The primary key **has** to be present in every item in a table.

Additionally, you can define [secondary indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.SecondaryIndexes) that help you with item retrieval. They can be either local or global, each with their own idiosyncrasies.

Comment: In SQL primary key becomes index by default, same things happens in DynamoDB?